SharePoint Health Analyer false positive on missing SPDataAccess role assignment
the SharePoint Health Analyzer in my SharePoint 2019 farm is throwing  lots of false positives that some service accounts are lacking the SPDataAccess role in ~all content databases.
Alas, this is not true. I checked the role assignments on those CDBs and all role assignments are correct. All service account with this error have the role SPDataAccess assigned.
Even when I use the SQL queries that P. Ignatius posted here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/184407/spha-rule-spdataaccess-for-projectqueueservice16-i?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-189426#newest-answer-comment
like
select count(1) FROM
sys.database_role_members AS i 
JOIN sys.database_principals AS n ON i.role_principal_id = n.principal_id
JOIN sys.database_principals AS m ON i.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
WHERE n.name = N'SPDataAccess' AND m.Name = N'MYDOMAIN\MyServiceAccount'                        


all is looking fine.
I even manually reassigned the
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'SPDataAccess', N'MYDOMAIN\MyServiceAccount';  

and clicked "Re-Analyze" in the SPHA rule, but the problem persists.
Any ideas?

Also posted here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1656610/sharepoint-health-analyer-false-positive-on-missin
